# Change order of Execution for Jmeter and run Pre-Processor before Config or use Environmental variable for FilePath of CSV DataSet Config

Tags: maven, jmeter

I am reading CSV File contents to pass to my HTTP Requests, Which I can do correctly, But the issue is the CSV file path, to read fro, is in one of the Environment variables.
I tried using a JSR223 PreProcessor to read the environment variable and set the path into a property, Then use the property value in the FilePath field,
But due to the order of execution of JMeter elements, The Congif elements are executed before Preprocessors, Even If I put them in SetUp threads.

I am a newbie to Jmeter tests. Looking for somebody to help on either how to change the order of execution(If Possible) to run the Config elements after Preprocessors, Or on how to directly get the Environment variable into the FilePath field of CSV DataSet Config?

I've tried using Setup threads to Preprocess and then the next thread to run the config but it doesn't work.

Comment: you can't, do you know path value before execution? if so you can send property, if not state your case

Comment: @user7294900 The path value is unknown before execution. It is saved in an Environment variable on the machine the Jmeter test runs in. The File contains the api-password for the Tests. Therefore I would first need to get the path from the Environment variable, Then read the CSV file from the path, and then pass the values from the CSV to the tests.

Answer (score 0):

You can parameterize the path to the CSV file using [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) like:

[image]

Once done you should be able to set the property value via [-J command-line argument](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override) like:

- on Windows

  ```
  jmeter -JfilePath=%your_environment_variable% -n -t test.jmx
  ```
- on Unix and derivatives:

  ```
  jmeter -JfilePath=$your_environment_variable -n -t test.jmx
  ```

See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization/) for more information on JMeter Properties and ways of setting and overriding them.

If you're running your JMeter test via Maven - you will need to declare the relevant property via [propertiesUser](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki/Modifying-Properties#5) section:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>jmeter</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <propertiesUser>
                        <filePath>${env.filePath}</filePath>
                    </propertiesUser>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <!-- Run JMeter tests -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jmeter</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <!-- Fail build on errors in test -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>jmeter-check-results</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>results</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: Hi was actually trying to use only the Jmeter GUI to run my tests and wanted a way for the GUI to take up the env variables.